# Using blank space from Text Field make application crashing

Tags: iphone, string

In my app I use a string passed from a UITextField. It works but when the user enters text with a blank space (i.e. 2 or more words), the application crash where I use it.

```
.h
NSString *nameReturned
IBOutlet UITextField  *nameField;

.m
nameReturned = nameField.text;
```

The point where the app crash is there:

```
NSLog(@"name returned  %@",nameReturned);    //here the NSLOg returns the string with the blanks spaces, I mean 2 or more word correctly
NSString *name =    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", nameReturned];  //there the app crash if blank spaces are present.
```

I use this string to obtain a url that I use for a URL request.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that would crash if nameReturned really is a string but, regardless, you shouldn't be using something a user entered as a format and you don't need a format at any time if all you're doing is copying one string.

Comment: Can you post your code where you set `nameRetrieved`?

Comment: I just edit the answer...the problems appaer onluy with 2 or more words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post more details.

**Its worked fine for me**

.h

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController {


    NSString *nameReturned;
    IBOutlet UITextField  *nameField;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField  *nameField;

-(IBAction)clickMe;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize nameField;

-(IBAction)clickMe{

nameReturned = [[nameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
NSLog(@"name returned  %@",nameReturned);    //here the NSLOg returns the string with the blanks spaces, I mean 2 or more word correctly
NSString *name =    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", nameReturned];  //there the app crash if blank spaces are present.
NSURL *uRL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:name];

    //release the  nameField in dealloc and nameReturned your after usage

}

@end
```

Comment: Tx for answering. the problem i am experimenting is about 2 (or more) words separatedfor a blank space. The app doesn't crash for a single word but with 2, yes it do.

Comment: Tx, it works! now the app does not crash.                             I just added   name=[nameReturned stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];           in order to replace the spce with the %20 for a correct url! thank you!